# Python tic-tac-toe using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe, tkinter

I recently made this tic-tac-toe program using tkinter, but I am quite new to tkinter, so I would be grateful for tips on how to improve the program. (Note that the actual tic-tac-toe logic is being done by the [python-tictactoe](https://pypi.org/project/python-tictactoe/) library.)

This is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

from tictactoe import Board
from tictactoe import X, O

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.pack()

board = Board()


def convert_to_str(player):
    return "X" if player == X else "O"


def push(i):
    pos = ((i + 1) % 3, i // 3)

    if board.is_empty(pos) and board.result() is None:
        squares[i].config(text=convert_to_str(board.turn))
        board.push(pos)

    # if there is a winner (use bool, because a draw is 0; so True only if board.result is 1 or 2)
    if bool(board.result()):
        for square in squares:
            if square.cget("text") == convert_to_str(board.result()):
                square.config(bg="green", fg="gold")

    # if it is a draw
    elif board.result() == 0:
        for square in squares:
            square.config(bg="yellow")


squares = [tk.Button(frame, text=" ", font=("Courier", 50), bg="white", command=lambda i=i: push(i)) for i in range(9)]

for i, square in enumerate(squares):
    square.grid(row=(i + 1) % 3, column=i // 3)

tk.mainloop()
```

This is what it looks like:

GUI:
[image: An image of the tkinter window]

Win:
[image: An image of the tkinter window where X has won]

Draw:
[image: An image of the tkinter window where there is a draw]

Comment: For a win wouldn't it be better if you only use the green background on the 3 squares that constituted the win?